# Filtered Gallery does not show as expected outside Powerapps Editor

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

So, I have a filtered gallery in the home screen of my app, and it works as expected in the PowerApps editor. However, I tried to test it outside of the editor and what I get is a blank screen. I have no idea how to troubleshoot this. At first, I thought it was the way I nested my If statement, but that wasn't the case after I tried using a non-nested If statement... The code below is what I used to filter the gallery...colHomeMenu is currently in my App OnStart property...

```
//This filters the home menu according to the role of the logged in user.

If(
    User().Email = Label7_1.Text,
    Filter(
        colHomeMenu,
        Label7.Text in SeenBy
    ),
    If(
        User().Email = lbl_UnitControls_DeptHead.Text,
        Filter(
            colHomeMenu,
            lbl_UnitControls_DeptHead.Text in SeenBy && lbl_UnitControls_DeptHead.Text = User().Email
        ),
        If(
            User().Email in lbl_UnitControls_MemEmails.Text,
            Filter(
                colHomeMenu,
                lbl_UnitControls_MemEmails.Text in SeenBy && User().Email in lbl_UnitControls_MemEmails.Text
            ),
            Filter(
                colHomeMenu,
                lbl_UnitControls_UnitHead.Text in SeenBy && lbl_UnitControls_UnitHead.Text = User().Email
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

This is what shows when I test it in the editor which is what it's supposed to be.

[image]

This is what I get when I test it outside the editor.

Any help with this will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you getting any delegation warnings in your formula?

Comment: Have you published the latest version?

Comment: You need to publish the latest version so that users will use your latest content

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP no I don't get any delegation warnings...@ChengFeng yes I published the latest version but it still didn't work. What I did in the end was to place a button somewhere where users can click so that it plays for them. I also noticed that sometimes it shows without users having to click anything, and other times it doesn't...